# Invoking mutual 2 way SSL webservice using CURL

Tags: web-services, ssl, curl, tls1.2

1)I created myfile.csr using the below command

```
req -out myfile.csr -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout myfile-pr.key
```

2. I sent myfile.csr to 3rd party to have it signed
3. 3rd party application signed and sent me serverfile.pem

Using these files would i be able to invoke a REST webservice using curl command. I tried the below command but it returned unauthorized error

```
curl --cacert ./serverfile.pem --key ./myfile-pr.key --cert ./myfile.csr --pass <password>   https://serverpost:port/getEmployeeInfo
```

Comment: Can be a misconfiguration on the server side, missing chain certificates on your site, certificate alone not being sufficient authentication, wrong certificate used even if you think it is the right one, wrong URL and possible more. Unfortunately it is impossible to reproduce anything based on the information in your question so one can only speculate about common problems.

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich  for your comments. I am able to invoke the webservice using soap-ui by adding the keystore file(signed certificate provided by 3rd party) serverfile.pem and the password. I was following the instruction in  https://downey.io/notes/dev/curl-using-mutual-tls. But I am not sure if --cacert is the signed certificate i received from 3rd party webservice application

Comment: If the application returns *"unauthorized"* then the TLS handshake itself worked. Therefor the problem might be that a deeper check of the client certificate is done after the handshake and that this fails. But it might also be completely unrelated to the certificate and complain because wrong user agent, wrong access method, wrong HTTP headers etc. Impossible to say.

Comment: the actual message is  "Status": {
      "code": "401-01",
      "message": "Unauthorized client failed to present  a valid digital certificate",

Comment: Could you please provide the **full** output when using `curl -v`

Comment: * Could not resolve host: application
* Closing connection 0
*   Trying 65.00.000.133...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to thridparty.com (65.00.000.133) port 443 (#1)
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with thridparty.com port 443 (step 1/3)
* schannel: disabled server certificate revocation checks
* schannel: verifyhost setting prevents Schannel from comparing the supplied target name with the subject names in server certificates.

Comment: * schannel: sending initial handshake data: sending 182 bytes...
* schannel: sent initial handshake data: sent 182 bytes
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with thridparty.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: failed to receive handshake, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with thridparty.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 2920
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 2920 length 4096
* schannel: received incomplete message, need more data

Comment: * schannel: SSL/TLS connection with thridparty.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 1176
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 4096 length 4096
* schannel: received incomplete message, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with thridparty.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 1024
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 5120 length 5120
* schannel: received incomplete message, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with thridparty.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 707

Comment: * schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 5827 length 6144
* schannel: a client certificate has been requested
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with thridparty.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 5827 length 6851
* schannel: sending next handshake data: sending 133 bytes...
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with thridparty.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 51
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 51 length 6851

Comment: * schannel: SSL/TLS handshake complete
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with thridparty.com port 443 (step 3/3)
* schannel: stored credential handle in session cache
> POST /api/test HTTP/1.1
> Host: thridparty.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 77
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: * upload completely sent off: 77 out of 77 bytes
* schannel: client wants to read 102400 bytes
* schannel: encdata_buffer resized 103424
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: encrypted data got 460
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 460 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data length: 431
* schannel: decrypted data added: 431

Comment: < HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Connection: close
Connection: close
< Content-Type: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 265
Content-Length: 265
< Date: Thu, 25 Mar 2021 15:16:00 GMT
Date: Thu, 25 Mar 2021 15:16:00 GMT
< Server: CA-API-Gateway/9.0
Server: CA-API-Gateway/9.0

Comment: <
{
  "backend": {
    "Status": {
      "code": "401-01",
      "message": "Unauthorized client failed to present  a valid digital certificate",
      "api": "edav1",
      "transaction_id": "12344",
      "time": "Thu Mar 25 03:16:00 2021"
    }
  }
}* Closing connection 1
* schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with thridparty.com port 443
* schannel: clear security context handle

Comment: Please, edit your question and add it nicely formatted so one can actually read it. It's not actually usable when spread over many comments without any formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `--cacert` is used to specify the file with the public certificate of the Certification Authority (CA). If you installed 3rd party CA certificate on your system, this option is not needed.

With the `--cert` you specify the signed client certificate which was issued to you based on your CSR. From `man curl`:

> -E, --cert <certificate[:password]>
> Tells  curl  to use the specified client certificate file when getting a file with HTTPS, FTPS or another SSL-based protocol. The certificate must be in PKCS#12 format if using Secure Transport, or PEM format if
> using any other engine.  If the optional password isn't specified, it will be queried for on the terminal. Note that this option assumes a "certificate" file that is the private key and the client certificate  concate‐
> nated! See -E, --cert and --key to specify them independently.

Currently, you are passing CSR (certificate signing request) via `--cert` parameter. Your command should look something like this:

```
curl --cacert ./3rd-party-ca-cert.pem --key ./myfile-pr.key --cert ./serverfile.pem --pass <password>   https://serverpost:port/getEmployeeInfo
```

As I mentioned, the `--cacert` might not be needed if you already added this CA (e.g. on ubuntu https://superuser.com/a/719047).

Check `serverfile.pem` to make sure it contains only client certificate, and not 3rd party CA certificate chain as well.

Comment: It did work. I should have looked at your comment before. I tried it now and it works. I tried    <br/>  curl --cacert ./serverfile.pem  --key ./myfile-pr.key --cert ./serverfile.pem  --pass test43@   https://serverpost:port/getEmployeeInfo

Answer (score 0):

> ...  schannel: sending initial handshake data: sending ....

curl does not support client certificates on the command line with SChannel. See [this bug report](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/1897) and [this todo](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/8494abfb1b1079b33d71c5b3ae97c59e3741f8a5/docs/TODO#L849).

Answer (score 0):

@SteffenUllrich: Sorry i should have formatted better.

Issue was i was trying curl in windows(curl 7.55.1). Not sure if it's version issue. Did the following command in Linux and it works

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out combine.p12 -inkey client-cert-pr.key -in serverSelfSigned-cert.pem 
openssl pkcs12 -in combine.p12 -out ile.key.pem -nocerts -nodes 
openssl pkcs12 -in combine.p12 -out   file.crt.pem -clcerts -nokeys 
curl -E ./file.crt.pem --key ./file.key.pem https://thirdpartyserver.com/employee
```

Notes:    
client-cert-pr.key: client private key    
serverselfsigned-cert.pem: self signed certificate sent by 3rd party

The below other 2 options also works. Thanks @bagljas

```
curl --cacert ./serverfile.pem  --key ./myfile-pr.key --cert ./serverfile.pem  --pass <passwrod>  https://serverpost:port/getEmployeeInfo

curl --key ./myfile-pr.key --cert ./serverfile.pem  --pass <passwrod>  https://serverpost:port/getEmployeeInfo
```

Same command doesn't work in windows